# Custom module template not detected

Tags: 8, theming

The page--404 suggestion is visible in the twig debug comments:

```
function amu_http_status_code_display_theme_suggestions_page(array $variables)
{
  $path_args = explode('/', trim(\Drupal::service('path.current')->getPath(), '/'));
  $suggestions = theme_get_suggestions($path_args, 'page');
  $http_error_suggestions = [
    'system.401' => 'page__401',
    'system.403' => 'page__403',
    'system.404' => 'page__404',
  ];
  $route_name = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getRouteName();
  if (isset($http_error_suggestions[$route_name])) {

    $suggestions[] = $http_error_suggestions[$route_name];
  }

  return $suggestions;
}
```

But it fails to consider the

> templates/page--404.html.twig

from my module.

I have tried this

```
function amu_http_status_code_display_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {

  $arguments= array(
      'template' => 'page--404',
      'base hook' => 'node',
  );

  // this is the name of the templates
  return array(
    'page--404' =>  $arguments,
  );
}
```

Comment: Yes, theme suggestions don't work for templates in a module. The second code example is the correct approach, but don't use `-` in a theme hook other than for the template, only underscores are allowed. And for a page template the base hook is `page`, not `node`.

Comment: thanks , i needed also the first code to make the suggestion for the status code route

Answer (score 1):

thanks to 4k4 comment, i have made it working

```
/**
 * Setting 40x template suggestions
 */
function amu_http_status_code_display_theme_suggestions_page(array $variables)
{
  $path_args = explode('/', trim(\Drupal::service('path.current')->getPath(), '/'));
  $suggestions = theme_get_suggestions($path_args, 'page');
  //mapping the route with its suggestion hook
  $http_error_suggestions = [
    'system.403' => 'page__403',
    'system.404' => 'page__404',
  ];
  $route_name = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getRouteName();
  if (isset($http_error_suggestions[$route_name])) {

    $suggestions[] = $http_error_suggestions[$route_name];
  }

  return $suggestions;
}




/*
 *
 * make drupal knows the templates are located in the module
 *
 * */
function amu_http_status_code_display_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {


  $arguments403= array(
    'template' => 'page--403',
    'base hook' => 'page',
  );

  $arguments404= array(
    'template' => 'page--404',
    'base hook' => 'page',
  );

  //mapping the hook with its template
  return array(
    'page__403' =>  $arguments403,
    'page__404' =>  $arguments404,

  );
}
```